# Use JSON file in Gephi

Tags: json, social-networking, gephi

I have a json file containing network data that I'd like to visualize using a network visualization software like Gephi. But Gephi does not accept this type of files. Is there a way to convert the json file or are there any other network visualization softwares out there that can? I am a Mac user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html) in Python, construct your graph and **Export** your graph in a format that Gephi can load such as `gexf`or `graphml`. See the link for examples of the supported formats. Apparently R is an option, too, provided that `igraph` has a json reader

Answer (score 0):

Visjs can import Gephi JSON and display it as a graph/network:

http://visjs.org/examples/network/data/importingFromGephi.html

You probably could adapt your JSON to fit this format.

Comment: "Gephi JSON" - does Gephi support a JSON based file format then?

Comment: @AnnanFay this was 2017, I do not remember how it work, but you can have a look here: https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/more.html and here: https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/
It does not look like Gephi is importing JSON but it may export it.